# Tesseract struggles do identify clear word

Tags: ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I have an image which is at abour 320dpi. I'm cropping out a section, making it grayscale and binarizing (threshold) it to make it clearer. This is how it looks:

[image]

It seems clear to me in that it should not be hard to identify, but tesseract never seem to be able to get the text. I've tried psm 6,7,8 but none of them solves it.

What am I doing wrong that tesseract (v3) doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply

- 1. Upsampling
- 2. [Simple Thresholding](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html)

Upsampling is required for the accurate recognition. Thresholding will make the features of the characters available.

Result of thresholding:

[image]

Now you read:

```
Allin
```

Code:

---

```py
import cv2
import pytesseract

img = cv2.imread('3Po5A.png')
gry = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
(h, w) = gry.shape[:2]
gry = cv2.resize(gry, (w*2, h*2))
thr = cv2.threshold(gry, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
txt = pytesseract.image_to_string(thr, config="--psm 6")
print(txt)
cv2.imshow("thr", thr)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Note that you can achieve the same result using different [preprocessing techniques](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/ImproveQuality.html).